# I have a List of a base custom object P, but I would like to know if any given P is of the inherited class Ph. Can that be done?

Tags: c#

I have a List of custom objects Project, two classes inherit from this one, ProjectsPerHour and PrePaidProjects.

I have a method on ProjectsPerHour to add absences but I can't know within this list which Project is a ProjectsPerHour.

How can I know if an object P in the list of Projects is either one of the inherited classes?

Using MVC.

Comment: You should avoid that as it make the code harder to maintain in the future if you add more classes.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`<OfType>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) to filter the list. You can use `Single()` if the filtered list contains a single item.

```
var list = new P[]
{
    new P(),
    new Ph()
};

var listOfJustPh = list.OfType<Ph>();
Ph ph = listOfJustPh.Single();
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, `OfType<Derived>()` not only filters those who are of of type  `Derived`, it also casts them so you can use them directly as needed.